# UITableViewController certain cell with certain picture size

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm currently working on a `UITableViewController` application where I've run into a road block! I have an array of images, titles etc. working perfectly! However there is first cell in the array, in which I want the picture to be a different size than pictures in the rest of the cells. I cannot find a way to resolve my problem because if I use an array in the `main.storyboard`, I get only one cell with one certain identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check if you are at the first cell. When you are you can define the `UIImageView` again with:

```
[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)]
```

after that you fill the image like you do with the other cell's.

Answer (score 0):

In the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: , check if the indexPath.row is equal to the first row and then handle the cell there.